# Coldfusion change output variable dynamically without reloading page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I know this has to be simple, but I just cannot wrap my brain around it.

For a simple example, I have a coldfusion page with 4 inputs and one output variable.  What I am trying to do is have all 4 values of the inputs do some math and be added together to display the sum in the output whenever any input is changed.  So realtime output value based on the input values.

```
<cfset multi1 = 1.5>
<cfset multi2 = 0>
<cfset multi3 = 2>
<cfset multi4 = 1>

<cfinput name="value1">
<cfinput name="value2">
<cfinput name="value3">
<cfinput name="value4">
```

Output shows:
(multi1 * value1)+(multi2 * value2)+(multi3 * value3)+(multi4 * value4)

Comment: To change this in real time would require javascript.

Comment: Not related to your question but, if multi2 really is 0, what's the point of value1?  Also, you can use CF's `toScript()` function to send the CF variables to javascript.  Then you can use JS events to do the math and display the result in a `<div>` or something like that.

Comment: I recommend to stop using cfinput and cfform and all those old school ColdFusion front end tags. This is a problem that can easily be solved using straight HTML and JavaScript and the form doesn’t need to be submitted. Learn how to do it that way first, and if the server needs to do the calculations, then you simply submit the form and output the results.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish what you need without any javascript involvement is to turn this into a self-posting form.  Also, I agree with @Redtopia to not use any antiquated `<cfform>` tags.